# It is a bad habit to pass whole parameters to a method as argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My concern looks like

Controller Concern:

```
module User
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def abc(params)
    ...
  end
end
```

and now I am calling this `abc` method from  my controller

Controller:

```
  class UserController < AdminController
    ...
    user = abc(params)
    ...
  end
```

So is it a bad habit to pass the whole parameter from my controller to the abc method?

Comment: Do you have to pass it at all? I thought that controller concerns could just access `params`.

Comment: @Stefan: ah, it's a concern indeed. Still I tend to pass parameters explicitly, even if the data is accessible as methods on the same instance. Makes this method more "pure".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I would let the controller / concern handle the params stuff and move the "pure" method into the corresponding model (or service object if it is too heavy).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is a bad practice, because, more often than not, you don't actually *need* the entirety of the `params` in that method. You need only a few keys from it, but you pass the whole thing anyway, to make your life easier *now*.

However, by doing this, you're making your life harder *later*. When the time comes to revisit/refactor this method, it's not obvious what do you *actually* use from `params`. You'll have to analyze all code paths within the method. This is unnecessary work.

Forget the refactoring, even. You'll have to do this every single time you want to call the method.

Compare these two invocations, for example

```
User.abc(params)
```

and

```
User.abc(params[:id], params[:email])
```

Which of these looks more "manageable"?

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. But suppose my param contains 5 keys out of which I am using 4 keys in abc method still I should pass those keys separately or is it ok to pass the whole param at that time?

Comment: @DaZedMiNaZGamernanimelover: If you pass the whole thing, what message does this convey to a future reader of your code? I think it says "I use ALL of `params`". And also does not give that reader a slightest idea of what keys are actually expected. Remember, code is written one time, but is read a thousand times after that. Optimize for readability.

Comment: And if there are many keys, you can pass it like `User.abc(params.slice(:id, :email, :foo, :bar))`. This is much cleaner.

Comment: @DaZedMiNaZGamernanimelover if you have many arguments or if the argument order / presence is irrelevant, you should consider using keyword arguments.

Comment: Actually in that case you should use keyword arguments instead of ordinal arguments. IMHO having a method with a bunch of ordinal arguments that do not have a logical order is actually worse since you have to lookup the method every time.

Comment: @max: depends on the number of arguments, yes.